# type 'bool' is not a subtype of type 'List<Post>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart

```
 if (snapshot.hasData) {
```

//i'm trying to get a data from json after creating a model class post but facing an error that bool has not a subtype of list

```
          List<Post> posts = snapshot.hasData as List<Post>;
          return ListView(
            children: posts
                .map((Post post) => ListTile(
                      title: Text(post.title),
              subtitle: Text(post.id.toString(),),
              onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PostDetails(post: post,))
              ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `snapshot.hasData` property as List, you need to change it to `snapshot.data`.
`snapshot.hasData` is a boolean that tell you is the current snapshot has any data or not.